# Silly detail enquiry about Prolog unification

Tags: list, prolog, unification, cons

In Prolog:

```
?-P=[A|B], P=[1,_].
P = [1, _G1091],
A = 1,
B = [_G1091]
```

B is shown as [_G1091] showing it's an uninstantiated variable. However, if I change a tiny bit...

```
?-P=[A|B], P=[1|_].
P = [1,B],
A = 1,
```

All of a sudden it's not interested in showing me that B is uninstantiated but still a variable ready to unify with anything.. how come? (I like to focus on weird details sometimes :) )

Comment: Thank you all three of you... you basically answered the question and made me understand it all of you so I'd want to put the grren V on all three of ya! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precise details of Prolog syntax are sometimes quite subtle. To get used to it  use `write_canonical/1` which shows you the term in functional notation:

```
?- write_canonical([A|B]).
'.'(_1,_2)
   true.
?- write_canonical([1,_]).
'.'(1,'.'(_1,[]))
   true.
```

May I recommend a "drill"-exercise to get used to Prolog's list notation:

Take some list like `[[1,2],3]` and now try to write it down in as many variants you can imagine.

```
?- [[1,2],3] == [[1,2],3|[]].
   true.
```

etc.

In many Prologs the toplevel lets you take the last input (often: cursor-up) such that you can re-edit the right-hand side rapidly.

Comment: Thanks! Good idea! I'm doing it :)

Answer (score 2):

In the first case:

```
?-P=[A|B], P=[1,_].
```

you are stating that `P` is a list with two elements, the first one being the number 1 (unified to variable A). Therefore, `B` has to be a list with one element (an unnamed variable).

On the other hand, in the second case:

```
?-P=[A|B], P=[1|_].
```

you are stating that `P` is a list with at least one element (1 again unified to `A`) but you are not stating anything else. `B` can be either an empty list, or a list with any amount of elements.

Comment: Aha so then it doesn't even prepare a variable for it? It doesn't even know what it might be there but it will accept anything that I claim is there and create anonymous variable(s) as it comes so to speak... if you know what I mean...

Comment: @fast-reflexes: the second case still has B unbound, so it will unify with any term. The first case will only unify B with a list of one term

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the second part of each query, the first amounts to

P=.(1,.(_,[]))

while the second amounts to

P=.(1,_)

In the first, B is bound to .(_,[]); that is, a list that contains an uninstantiated variable

In the second, B is bound to an uninstantiated variable

When a variable is just bound to an uninstantiated variable, there's no point in showing it; in the first example it's bound to something with some additional structure, so there is a point in showing it.